# Convert index to datetime in pandas using customized parsing function

Tags: pandas

I'm using the pandas built-in DataReader to download data from the Fama-French data library. The dates are initially just integers in `yyyymm` format:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
ff = web.DataReader("F-F_Research_Data_Factors", "famafrench")[0]
ff.head()
```

[image]

I want to convert the index to a datetime, where the date is the last day of the month. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
ff.reset_index(inplace=True)

import calendar
def dateParser(dt):
    yyyy = int(dt[0:4])
    mm = int(dt[4:6])
    dd = calendar.monthrange(yyyy,mm)[1]   #last day of month
    return pd.datetime(yyyy,mm,dd)

ff['date'] = ff['index'].astype(str).apply(dateParser)
ff.index = ff['date']

ff.drop(['index', 'date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Is there a faster/more elegant way to accomplish this? For example, is there a way to apply `dateParser` directly to the index (perhaps inplace) so I don't have to `reset_index` first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Pandas dataframe index value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110721/how-to-change-pandas-dataframe-index-value)

Comment: I think it's different. I'm asking about applying a date function to an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [35]: ff = web.DataReader("F-F_Research_Data_Factors", "famafrench")[0]

In [36]: ff.head()
Out[36]: 
        1 Mkt-RF  2 SMB  3 HML  4 RF
192607      2.96  -2.30  -2.87  0.22
192608      2.64  -1.40   4.19  0.25
192609      0.36  -1.32   0.01  0.23
192610     -3.24   0.04   0.51  0.32
192611      2.53  -0.20  -0.35  0.31

In [38]: ff.index
Out[38]: 
Int64Index([192607, 192608, 192609, 192610, 192611, 192612, 192701, 192702, 192703, 192704, 
            ...
            201407, 201408, 201409, 201410, 201411, 201412, 201501, 201502, 201503, 201504],
           dtype='int64', length=1066)

In [39]: ff.index = pd.to_datetime(ff.index,format='%Y%m') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

In [40]: ff.index
Out[40]: 
DatetimeIndex(['1926-07-31', '1926-08-31', '1926-09-30', '1926-10-31', '1926-11-30', '1926-12-31', '1927-01-31', '1927-02-28', '1927-03-31', '1927-04-30', 
               ...
               '2014-07-31', '2014-08-31', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-30', '2014-12-31', '2015-01-31', '2015-02-28', '2015-03-31', '2015-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1066, freq='M', tz=None)

In [41]: ff.head()
Out[41]: 
            1 Mkt-RF  2 SMB  3 HML  4 RF
1926-07-31      2.96  -2.30  -2.87  0.22
1926-08-31      2.64  -1.40   4.19  0.25
1926-09-30      0.36  -1.32   0.01  0.23
1926-10-31     -3.24   0.04   0.51  0.32
1926-11-30      2.53  -0.20  -0.35  0.31
```

Note that its actually faster to convert the index like following as the format has a fast path.

```
pd.to_datetime(ff.index*100+1,format='%Y%m%d') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
```