# how can I add column called "group" into DataFrame multiindex

Tags: python-3.x

I am a novice in python,  I have question about how add multiindex level to DataFrame.
for example I have DataFrame like this 
[image]

how can I add column called "group" into  DataFrame multiindex like this
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to add new levels to a DataFrame's index:

- Use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) to build a new index:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3]})
  df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index, ['A','B','C']], 
                                       names=['id','group'])
  print(df)
  ```

  yields

  ```
            val
  id group     
  0  A        1
  1  B        2
  2  C        3
  ```

  [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) could also help
  you build new `MultiIndex`s -- which to use depends on what your inputs look like.

  Note that `MultiIndex`s are not mutable -- you can't add new levels to an existing `MultiIndex`. To change the index of a DataFrame you simply assign a new index to the DataFrame's `index` attribute. [See also the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for a more comprehensive discussion of `MultiIndex`s.
- Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to move column values into the index:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','B','C'],'val':[1,2,3]})
  #   group  val
  # 0     A    1
  # 1     B    2
  # 2     C    3

  df = df.set_index(['group'], append=True)
  print(df)
  ```

  yields

  ```
           val
    group     
  0 A        1
  1 B        2
  2 C        3
  ```

Of these two methods, [reassigning the index is generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110955/190597) than calling `set_index`.